# Установка программ в linux без запрашивания пароля

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, sudo

Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе в терминал `sudo apt-get install <какая-то программа>` не приходилось потом набирать пароль и в одну строчку согласиться со всем ?

Comment: В выводе help'а (apt-get --help) есть вот упоминание вот такого флага: `-y   отвечать «Да» на все вопросы, сами вопросы при этом не выводить`

Comment: Здесь (http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=134044) и здесь (http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=66582.0) упоминаются решения о пароле для sudo. Вкратце: `echo <ваш пароль> | sudo -S apt-get -y install <какая-то программа>` подходит. Однако опытные юзеры с вышеупомянутых форумов советуют (и я с ним согласен) разобраться с `sudoers` либо `visudo`. Если вам не хочется набирать пароль вообще, то указанное мной решение не для вас.

Comment: Не, я пишу скрипт для удаленного разворачивания проекта по ssh. Не очень круто все время пароль вводить при запуске скрипта по многу раз. Поэтому первое решение более актуально. Спасибо. :)

Comment: *Не, я пишу скрипт для удаленного разворачивания проекта по ssh.* - возьмите chef-zero, ansible, capistrano, fabric или аналог, не надо заниматься такими вещами через баш

Comment: @hunter Если думать о какой-то безопасности, то решение хуже ввода пароля через `echo` придумать сложно.

Comment: Вкратце, настройка `sudoers` для выполнения команд через `sudo` без пароля здесь: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43135/allowing-a-user-to-use-sudo-without-a-password или здесь: `man sudoers`

Comment: @andy.37 так вот в том то и прикол почему мне оно не нравится.

Comment: Как один из не самых секурных вариантов - настроить sshd на авторизацию только по ключу и разрешить логиниться под рутом. Вариант вполне рабочий, но если кто завладеет закрытым ключиком - пиши "пропало". В общем это больше академический вариант. А так я бы посомтрел в сторону `puppet` или `ansible` как советовали выше.

Comment: я бы рекомендовал один раз в начале сеанса сделать `sudo su` и работать от root'а

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, это не автоматизированно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. для того, чтобы программа *sudo* не запрашивала пароль для пользователя *user1* при выполнении им команды `sudo apt-get ...`, добавьте в файл с произвольным именем в каталоге `/etc/sudoers.d` такую примерно строку:

   ```
   user1 ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get
   ```

   редактировать файлы `/etc/sudoers` и `/etc/sudoers.d/*` лучше через «обёртку» *visudo*, которая, прежде чем реально перезаписать файл, произведёт проверку корректности синтаксиса, и, если будут найдены ошибки, предложит продолжить редактирование, т.е., вы не окажетесь «у разбитого корыта», когда из-за внесённой ошибки не сможете запустить `sudo что-угодно`.

   запустить *visudo* можно так:

   ```
   $ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/файл-с-произвольным-именем
   ```

   если по каким-то причинам вас не устраивает редактор, который при этом запустится, его можно указать явно. пара примерев:

   ```
   $ sudo EDITOR=vim visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/файл-с-произвольным-именем
   $ sudo EDITOR=nano visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/файл-с-произвольным-именем
   ```
2. для того, чтобы программа *apt-get* «считала», что вы на все её вопросы ответили утвердительно, добавьте при её запуске опцию `-y` (`--yes`, `--assume-yes`).

---

документация:

- `man sudo`
- `man sudoers`
- `man visudo`