# rsync с правами sudo

Tags: debian, резервное-копирование, sudo, rsync

Есть задача - синхронизировать содержимое папки /home/* между двумя серверами.
Команда выглядит следующим образом:

```
rsync --archive --acls --xattrs --one-file-system -e "ssh -T -c arcfour -o Compression=no -x" --exclude=".*" --size-only --log-file=/home/backup/rsync.log remote@server_dns.ru:/home/* /home/backup/
```

Бэкап сервер ходит на удаленный сервер через ssh-key под юзера backup.
Но, на удаленном сервере в папке /home/* много пользователей у которых могут быть разные права на чтение их файлов и не принадлежат эти файлы соответственно юзеру или группе backup.
Как выполнить rsync с командой sudo на этом сервере, что бы можно было копировать файлы независимо от их владельца и прав.

Как вариант пробовал всех пользователей добавлять в группу backup и менял всем файлам права на возможность чтения группе. Но за этим нужно постоянно  следить и выглядит костыльно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно воспользоваться опцией `--rsync-path` со значением `"sudo rsync"` ([предварительно разрешив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552377/178576) на отдалённой машине пользователю, под именем которого подключаемся, выполнять `sudo rsync` без ввода пароля).

согласно `man rsync`:

> --rsync-path=PROGRAM
>   Use this to specify what program is to be run on the remote machine  to  start-up  rsync.

вольный перевод:

> используйте для указания программы, которая будет выполнена на отдалённом компьютере для запуска *rsync*.

---

пример:

1. на удалённом компьютере создаём файл и делаем его нечитабельным для всех:

   ```
   $ touch /tmp/file; chmod ugo= /tmp/file
   ```
2. на локальной машине пытаемся скопировать его (от имени рядового пользователя `user`) и получаем ошибку:

   ```
   $ rsync user@host:/tmp/file /tmp
   rsync: send_files failed to open "/tmp/file": Permission denied (13)
   rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1536) [generator=3.0.9]
   ```
3. а теперь воспользуемся описанной опцией ([предварительно разрешив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552377/178576) на отдалённой машине пользователю `user` выполнять `sudo rsync` без ввода пароля) — и копирование произойдёт успешно:

   ```
   $ rsync --rsync-path="sudo rsync" user@host:/tmp/file /tmp
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Можно зашить пароль `sudo` в тело скрипта, который делает бэкап:

`--rsync-path="echo <PASSWORD> | sudo -Sv && sudo rsync"`

Полная команда:

```
rsync --rsync-path="echo <PASSWORD> | sudo -Sv && sudo rsync" --archive --acls --xattrs --one-file-system -e "ssh -T -c arcfour -o Compression=no -x" --exclude=".*" --size-only --log-file=/home/backup/rsync.log  remote@server_dns.ru:/home/* /home/backup/
```

Данный подход не совсем безопасный, так как пароль виден в дереве процессов. Лучше заменить на конструкцию вида:
  `--rsync-path="cat /path/to/my_password.txt | sudo -Sv && sudo rsync"`
, где `my_password.txt` копируется на сервер до снятия бэкапа и потом удаляется (лучше удалять командой `shred`)