# Иправление syntax error с sudo

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

Установлена на VDS у меня Ubuntu 14.04. Если прописать просто `sudo`, то получим весьма неприятное:

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 9 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 9 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 9 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 9 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 10 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 11 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 12 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 13 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 14 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 15 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 16 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 17 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 18 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 19 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 19 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 9
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

То есть тут уже понятно, что с `/etc/sudoers` скорее всего что-то не так. Вот содержание `/etc/sudoers`:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

    # Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Но по содержанию файла `/etc/sudoers` все должно быть нормально. В чем еще может быть проблема? Или все таки она в `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: пальцем в небо... может концы строк виндовые?

Comment: @Fat-Zer я так понимаю, имеете ввиду, что я из под винды переписывал содержимое?

Comment: Возможно что вам сюда https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file

Comment: @defrag там немного другое походу

Comment: @e4sylock, я имею в виду, что это синдром... как именно они  туда попали — не знаю... `cat -A` для подтверждения, sed -i 's/\r//' (с соответствующей сменой прав) для фикса...

Comment: 1. способы редактирования файла - выше по ссылке. 2. исправление содержимого: [`dos2unix`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=dos2unix). 3. чтобы избежать подобного в дальнейшем, редактируйте этот файл **только** с помощью программы-обёртки [`visudo`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552377/178576)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin благодарен вам. спасибо за информацию.